# How can I secure my PHP queries against SQL injection without using PDO or prepared statements?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

i want to secure my sql queries without pdo or prepare statement
can this function do ?

```
function sql_escape($string)
{
    $string =   iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string),'UTF-8//IGNORE',$string);
    $string =   addslashes($string);
    $string =   preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\0xB4\0x60\0x96\0x97\0x95\0x94\0x93\0x92\0x91\0x84\0x82\0x3B\0x8A]/', '', $string);
    $string =   addslashes($string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: It's not just a matter of security, but of deprecated functions as well. They made [new] good things for you, use them : ))

Comment: `\x80- ` (space, 0x20) is an invalid range.

Comment: @Gumbo the space came while pasting the code :)

Comment: Don't trust REGEX for data validation.

Comment: @RobW Could U tell me Why ? :)

Comment: If you have to use REGEX to even attempt to do data validation (in most scenarios), then you're doing it wrong. `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.` - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: And by data validation, I mean "validating the data is OK for the database"-validation.

Comment: All you need to do is escape any character the database will interpret as a string terminator or otherwise special character. Everything else is just pointless song and dance with which you're destroying the original value little by little. [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 4):

No, use the supplied escape function. For `mysqli` this is `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Don't reinvent the wheel, especially if it's a very complex wheel and you're not really sure it works in all conditions.

Comment: Ops :)  ... But i don't like this words " Don't reinvent the wheel "
I just wanna to learn more and more !

Comment: I wonder why this answer is so upvoted. mysqli_real_escape_string do not protect anything from SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

Like many PHP folks you are confusing escaping with protection from injection. So, someday your site will be hacked and you'll come here ready to learn something useful at last.